# What does it mean to reduce one polynomial "modulo" another polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I'm familiar with the concept of modular arithmetic, but only with constants. I've never seen it with polynomials before. How would I reduce $q(x)$ modulo $p(x)$? Do polynomial long division and take the remainder?

Comment: More or less, yes. It's the same as with integers in that regard.

Comment: It's explained here pretty clearly -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you said, if $q(x)$ can be divided with remainder by $p(x)$, you can keep $r(x)$ instead of $q(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

It means to calculate the remainer when dividing $q(x)$ by $p(x)$ using long division.